# Finding pairs that share multiple commonalities in a large dataset

Tags: python

I have a csv file with nearly 1 million lines. Each line is a unique user with their favorite hobbies listed.
Example:

```
userID    hobbyIDs
uu0000001    ['hh0079187', 'hh0133268', 'hh0140845', 'hh0163721', 'hh9121232']
uu0000002    ['hh0011390', 'hh0494421']
uu0000003    ['hh0494421', 'hh0011390', 'hh0912384', 'hh0163721']
...
```

What I am trying to do is find pairs of users who share at least 2 hobbies. So using the previous example, the result should be:

```
userPairIDs    pairHobbyIDs
(uu0000002,uu0000003)    ['hh0011390', 'hh0494421']
```

The issue is that my current approach is incredibly slow, and I am unsure as to how I can optimize it. I tried using pandas but quickly ran into memory issues. Any insight as to how I can improve would be appreciated.

```
csv.field_size_limit(1000000000)

fp = '../data/user_hobbies.tsv'

user_hobby= defaultdict(set)

with open(fp, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        user_id= row[0]
        hobbies = eval(row[1])  # Convert string representation of list to actual list
        user_hobby[user_id].update(hobbies)

# Find pairs of actors who share at least 2 hobbies
pairs = []
for user1 in user_hobby:
    for user2 in user_hobby:
        if user1 < user2:  # prevent duplicates
            shared_hobbies = user_hobby[user1].intersection(user_hobby[user2])
            if len(shared_hobbies) >= 2:
                pairs.append((user1, user2, shared_hobbies))
```

Comment: You could first parse your list to create a dictionary {hobby: set of users}, then for each user and for each pair of hobbies of this user, look at the intersection of the 2 sets of users. This will turn an O(n^2) algorithm into a more or less linear one.

Comment: Off-topic, but `eval` is not necessary here and could be unsafe. Use `ast.literal_eval` instead, then the worst case scenario is the interpreter crashes instead of arbitrary code execution.

Comment: Also beside the point, `for user1 in user_hobby: ... if user1 < user2:` is equivalent to [`combinations(user_hobby, r=2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), I believe.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really built for suggestions, and titles should be specific enough to describe the problem, so please [edit] accordingly. See [ask] for tips. You might put something like *"How can I **efficiently** find pairs that share multiple commonalities in a large dataset?"* It might also help to describe the current performance, like, if I've got this correct, `for user1 in user_hobby: for user2 in user_hobby:` is *O(n^2)* and the intersection is *O(m\*p)* where *m, p* are the lengths of the sets, so the total is *O(n^2 \* m\*p)*.

Comment: For specific tips see [What makes a "good" performance question on SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412875/4518341) TLDR: be specific, show your attempt (done), and think about the possibilities/constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll first create two dictionaries {user: hobbies} and {hobby: users}, which is accomplished by parsing the file in linear time.

Then for each user, and for each pair of hobbies, we only have to intersect the sets of associated users.

```
import csv
from ast import literal_eval
from itertools import combinations

fp = 'user_hobbies.tsv'

hobbies_dict = {}
users_dict = {}
with open(fp, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for row in csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t'):
        user, hobbies = row[0], literal_eval(row[1])
        users_dict[user] = hobbies
        for hobby in hobbies:
            hobbies_dict.setdefault(hobby, set()).add(user)

user_pairs = set()
for user, hobbies in users_dict.items():
    for hobbies_pair in combinations(hobbies, 2):
        common_users = set.intersection(hobbies_dict[hobbies_pair[0]], hobbies_dict[hobbies_pair[1]])
        common_users.remove(user)
        for other_user in common_users:
            if (other_user, user) not in user_pairs:
                user_pairs.add((user, other_user))


print(user_pairs)
# {('uu0000002', 'uu0000003')} (based on your examples)
```

Edit: improved version with only one loop, more time (only one loop) and memory (no users_dict) efficient:

```
user_pairs = set()
hobbies_dict = {}
with open(fp, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for row in csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t'):
        user, hobbies = row[0], literal_eval(row[1])
        for hobbies_pair in combinations(hobbies, 2):
            common_users = set.intersection(
                hobbies_dict.get(hobbies_pair[0], set()),
                hobbies_dict.get(hobbies_pair[1], set()))
            for other_user in common_users:
                user_pairs.add((user, other_user))
        for hobby in hobbies:
            hobbies_dict.setdefault(hobby, set()).add(user)

print(user_pairs)
# {('uu0000003', 'uu0000002')}
```

Comment: I just had an insight: doing the 2nd part at the same time hobbies_dict is created (inside the file parsing loop) will cross-check each user with the already parsed user, which will be faster AND remove the need to de-duplicate the user pairs as well as the need to create users_dict.